# Create multiple graphs in tensorflow under same thread

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to create graphs from different sessions by :

```
sess1 = tf.Session()
print(sess1)
print(sess1.graph)

sess2 = tf.Session()
print(sess2)
print(sess2.graph)


sess3 = tf.Session()
print(sess3)
print(sess3.graph)
```

and the result is

```
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x14305b2b0>
<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x14305ba20>
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x14305b9b0>
<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x14305ba20>
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x14305b908>
<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x14305ba20>
```

I don't understand, since I expected different sessions would have different graphs, but in this case, different sessions shared the same graph object... ?

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#class_session):

> If no graph argument is specified when constructing the session, the
>   default graph will be launched in the session.

And that's why you get the same graph for different sessions. To solve it, you can simply provide a graph when creating the session:

```
sess1 = tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
print(sess1)
print(sess1.graph)

sess2 = tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
print(sess2)
print(sess2.graph)


sess3 = tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
print(sess3)
print(sess3.graph)
```

Which results in:

```
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x10589c9d0>
<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x104729d10>
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x114d0afd0>
<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x114cf8c50>
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x114d0ae50>
<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x114d0af90>
```

Comment: Thank you! , this answer helped me solve a serious problem. I know it's against site rules to thank someone on a thread but this really helped me. I was suspecting something like this as the solution but this was really helpful.